# How to catch exception of a method of session bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a stateless session bean with a method which throws an exception (which extends from Exception).

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyBean {
    ...
    public void myMethod() throws MyException {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I am not able to catch the exception.

```
try {
    myBean.myMethod
} catch (MyException e) {
    ...
}
```

Here is stack:

`WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[MyServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet MyServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: example/MyException
    at $Proxy327.myMethod(Unknown Source)
    at example.EJB31_Generated_MyBean_Intf_Bean_.myMethod(Unknown Source)
    at example.MyServlet.processRequest(MyServlet.java:36)
    at example.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:71)
        ...`

I think, it's because calling the bean method goes through proxy. How can I catch the exception? Or methods throwing exceptions in a session bean should be avoided? - I hope not.

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm not able to catch the exception"? What happens when MyException is thrown from the bean method?

Comment: The same when you don't catch exception. I added stack to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the stacktrace shows it's actually an IllegalAccessError which is thrown... see its API doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html

you wont be able to catch this by adding `catch (Exception e) {...}`... as it's an Error, which is not a subclass of Exception. If you REALLY want to catch it, you would have to add a `catch (Throwable t) {...}` which I highly discourage. Rather find the reason for the error being thrown. I think we need to see more of your code...

As the API says "Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed"... did you redeploy on server and client to be sure to use the same interface definition?

Comment: I forgot to make the exception public. I have to apologize to JaveEE for this accusation.